Addition Attributes into existing JOLT
I have following json input and I need to get 2 additional attributes (head,foot) into the output json using existing Jolt. How I can do that?
JSONs and JOLT scripts are attached.
Input JSON:
[
  {
    "PropertyName": "KER ZONE 1",
    "head": "13084",
    "foot": "48b4e"
  },
  {
    "Properties": [
      {
        "PropertyName": "KER ZONE 1",
        "Property": [
          {
            "StartTime": "2023-04-03",
            "Data": [
              {
                "GPSY": "45.28",
                "GPSX": "-3.24",
                "Val": "11.0",
                "Metric": "mvw"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "45.28",
                "GPSX": "-3.24",
                "Val": "2231",
                "Metric": "Hum"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "45.28",
                "GPSX": "-3.24",
                "Val": "0.00",
                "Metric": "wat"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "45.28",
                "GPSX": "-3.24",
                "Val": "58.82",
                "Metric": "temp"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "33.27",
                "GPSX": "-4.29",
                "Val": "0.00",
                "Metric": "wat"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "33.27",
                "GPSX": "-4.29",
                "Val": "9.8",
                "Metric": "mvw"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "33.27",
                "GPSX": "-4.29",
                "Val": "2206",
                "Metric": "Hum"
              },
              {
                "GPSY": "33.27",
                "GPSX": "-4.29",
                "Val": "58.28",
                "Metric": "temp"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "CallStatus": "1"
  }
]

Output JSON:
[
  {
    "Hum": "2231",
    "Road_1": "SD",
    "Road_2": "SF",
    "Temp": 14.9,
    "Temp_F": 58.82,
    "Time": "2023-04-03",
    "X": "-3.24",
    "Y": "45.28",
    "mvw": 11,
    "head": "13084",
    "foot": "48b4e"
  },
  {
    "Hum": "2206",
    "Road_1": "SD",
    "Road_2": "SF",
    "Temp": 14.6,
    "Temp_F": 58.28,
    "Time": "2023-04-03",
    "X": "-4.29",
    "Y": "33.27",
    "mvw": 9.8,
    "head": "13084",
    "foot": "48b4e"
  }
]

JOLT:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "@2,StartTime": "@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.Time",
                  "GPS*": "@(1,GPSY).@(1,GPSX).&",
                  "@Val": "@(1,GPSY).@(1,GPSX).@Metric"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Temp_C": "=doubleSum(@(1,temp),-32)",
          "Temp": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,Temp_C),1.8)",
          "temp": "=toDouble",
          "mvw": "=toDouble",
          "hum": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //Hard coded values
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Road_1": "SD",
          "Road_2": "SF"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&3.&",
          "GPSY": "&2.&3.Y",
          "GPSX": "&2.&3.X",
          "mvw": "&2.&3.mvw",
          "hum": "&2.&3.Hum",
          "temp": "&2.&3.Temp_F"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "wat": "",
        "Temp_C": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

Thank you

You can use the following specs :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "head|foot": "Outer.&",//pick the desired attributes only and nest them in a common object
        "Properties": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "@Val": "&6.@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.Val.@Metric", //match all Metric vs. Val in order to prepare for filtering out by "Hum" within the next spec 
                    "@2,StartTime": "&6.@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.Time",
                    "#SD": "&6.@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.Road_1",
                    "#SF": "&6.@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.Road_2",
                    "*PS*": "&6.@1,GPSY.@1,GPSX.&(0,2)"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Properties": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "Val": {
              "Tmp_C": "=doubleSum(@(1,temp),-32)",
              "Temp": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,Tmp_C),1.8)",
              "mvw": "=toDouble",
              "Temp_F": "=toDouble(@(1,temp))",
              "Hum": "=toInteger"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "P*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@3,Outer": { "*": "&3_&2.&" },
            "Val": {
              "Hum|mvw|Tem*": "&3_&2.&"
            },
            "*": {
              "0": "&3_&2.&1" //pick only one component up from the repeating multiple values from each array
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //convert to array of objects with no keys 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]


[{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "0": {
    "head": "head",
    "foot": "foot"
  },
  "1": {
    "Properties": {
      "*": {
        "Property": {
          "*": {
            "StartTime": {
              "*": {
                "Data": {
                  "*": {
                    "GPSY": "[&5].Y",
                    "GPSX": "[&5].X",
                    "Val": "[&5].@(2,Metric)",
                    "Metric": {
                      "temp": "[&4].Temp_F",
                      "mvw": "[&4].mvw",
                      "Hum": "[&4].Hum"
                    },
                    "@(2,head)": "[&4].head",
                    "@(2,foot)": "[&4].foot"
                  }
                },
                "@": {
                  "": "[&3].Time"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}},{
"operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "Temp_C": "=doubleSum(@(1,Temp_F),-32)",
    "Temp": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,Temp_C),1.8)",
    "Temp_F": "=toDouble",
    "mvw": "=toDouble",
    "Hum": "=toInteger"
  }
}},{
"operation": "default",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "Road_1": "SD",
    "Road_2": "SF"
  }
}},{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "Time": "&1.Time",
    "Y": "&1.Y",
    "X": "&1.X",
    "mvw": "&1.mvw",
    "Hum": "&1.Hum",
    "Temp": "&1.Temp",
    "Temp_F": "&1.Temp_F",
    "Road_1": "&1.Road_1",
    "Road_2": "&1.Road_2",
    "head": "&1.head",
    "foot": "&1.foot"
  }
}},{
"operation": "cardinality",
"spec": {
  "*": "ONE"
}},{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "*": "[]"
}},{
"operation": "remove",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "wat": "",
    "Temp_C": ""
  }
}}]

This Jolt spec will produce the desired output JSON with the head and foot attributes included.

Thank you, but this jolt is giving me some errors.
Error running the Transform.
JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:0.
@ Shiftr key, can not have children.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
